# How to group Array & Objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an array with 3 Objects, however the ***second*** Object does not have an array inside the '*Data*' Object.

I need to do an ng-repeat for each 'Artist' in the correct order, however the second object is causing issues.  How would I combine each Object together?

In my Factory, I set up a call to receive three response from three different API. I set a promise for each one so they come in a the exact order I call them.

**FACTORY**

```
.factory('timeline', function($http, $q) {    

    var promise1 = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://api.example.com/last/3/?limit=3"
    });
    var promise2 = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://api.example.com/current/3/"
    });
    var promise3 = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://api.example.com/next/3/?limit=3"
    });

    return {
       data: $q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
    }

})
```

In my controller, I get the response like so.

```
[
Object
   config 
   data: [Array 3]
     -0: Object 
         artist : 'Artist'
         title  : 'Title'
     -1: Object
     -2: Object
,

Object
   config 
   data: Object
     artist : 'Artist'
     title  : 'Title
,

Object
   config 
   data: [Array 3]
     -0: Object 
         artist : 'Artist'
         title  : 'Title'
     -1: Object
     -2: Object
]
```

***CONTROLLER***

My Attempt to filter using Underscore.

```
.controller('StationCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, timeline) {

timeline.data.then(function(musicData) {
    var row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < musicData.length; i++) {
        var data = _.filter(musicData[i].data, function(x){
            row.push(x);
        })         
    }       
})
})
```

***My Goal*** eventually if possible would be to combine everything in order

```
Object
   data: [Array 7]
     -0: Object 
     -1: Object
     -2: Object
     -3: Object
     -4: Object
     -5: Object
     -6: Object
,
```

I am still trying to figure out how to work with Objects & Arrays, any help/tips would be great.

Comment: how do you want to combine config objects into one?

Comment: Sorry removed that, don't want to combine config actually, just data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple approach of how you can solve your problem without underscore. You just need to check whether your data is an object or an array.

```
var arr = [
  { data: [{ artist: 'Artist' }, { artist: 'Artist2' }]},
  { data: { artist: 'Artist3' } },
  { data: [{ artist: 'Artist4' }]}
];

var flattened = [];

arr.forEach(function (el) {
  if(Array.isArray(el.data)) {
    flattened = flattened.concat(el.data);
  } else {
    flattened.push(el.data);
  }
});
```

See example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faxotazafu/1/).

Comment: Thank you! I'll need to study Array.isArray, never used that before

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I think you should send an array only for 2nd object with its length as 1. If the API is not in your control i.e. 3rd party or anything else then we can look forward to solve the issue in other way.

Comment: Yeah the API is not my control, let me see if I can do that now

Comment: You can also implement an alternate approach, i.e. before you set the data in scope, manipulate it and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip out the underscore and just do a nested for:

```
.controller('StationCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, timeline) {

timeline.data.then(function(musicData) {
    var row = [];
    var dataElement;
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < musicData.length; i++) {
        dataElement = musicData[i].data;
        if(typeof dataElement === 'object') {
            row.push(dataElement)
        } else if(typeof dataElement === 'array') {
            for(j = 0; j < dataElement.length; j++) {
                row.push(dataElement[j]);
            }
        }        
    }       
})
})
```